# Imported Android project error

Tags: android, import, project

first I am sorry my bad english
I imported a in operation android project to eclipse.There is not error on codes in eclipse.When I started emulator throwing a error: "Unfortunately Twitter Arama(project's title) has stopped".I had these lines:
What can I do?

error opening trace file:

```
No such file or directory (2)
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/listviewsample/MainActivity; (10)
Link of class 'Lcom/example/listviewsample/MainActivity;' failed
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewsample/com.example.listviewsample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.listviewsample.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.listviewsample-1.apk
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
….
….
….
….
….
….

Sending signal. PID: 2024 SIG: 9
```

Comment: try cleaning the project and build again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: If there are .jar files, put it into the libs folder in application workspace. or if library, then build the library first and then build your non-library(runnable) application.

Step 2: Confirm application is referring to the library if any.

Reason for this exception:
Compiler cannot find definition for MainActivity class.